# How to force a jar to run in java 7?

Tags: java, jar, version

I made a Runnable Jar that will run as service in windows, but the final pc that will execute him, has 3 versions of java installed, 1.3, 1.6 and 1.7, and my jar needs to be executed with 1.7, because him uses classes that are present only in 1.7+ version, o don't know how are configured the environiment variables, my question is:

Is possible to force my code to run in java 1.7?

Comment: Did you check if there was some environment variable defining which java is used as default ?

Comment: We'll need more information. How is the jar run? You've said in a comment that this is a server, so presumably some process will run it, it's not just being run from the command line... What kind of server environment is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without persistently resetting your path environments. Just use the absolute path to your jre/jdk instead of typing "java": e.g.: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"\java -jar foo.jar`, same goes for MacOS and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Set your JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variable to point to the Java 7 directory.

See https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them to know how to do it.

Comment: Not very appropriate answer.

Comment: The problem is that i don't have permission to do that, it's a server, and have others java programs running =/

Comment: You can do it in a batch file... See how tomcat starts, you will have a good example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

- Rather than setting path/classpath at top level, you should create a
  batch file and set path/classpath there.
- Then command to run your jar.